# ISO standards for .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, standards, iso

Does anyone know the ISO standard that covers .NET 3.5?  I found ISO/IEC 23270:2006, but I am not sure if this is the right/latest one.  I need to put this in my SRS document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing such as .net standard. ISO/IEC 23270:2006 is for C# another C# standard would be ECMA-334

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 23270:2006 is the standard that covers C# as such. There is no ISO standard for the .NET Framework itself. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm digging out an old thread, but I wanted to append the following information:

There is a so-called `.net standard`, which defines a common API for the various .NET frameworks (.NET core, Mono, Xamarin, Universal ....):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

What you actually mean is the ISO standard `ISO 23270:2017`, which is currently under revision. The previous version is `ICS 35.060 / ISO 23270:2006` which can be found here:
https://www.iso.org/standard/42926.html

It corresponds the ECMA standard `ECMA-334:2017`, which is also currently under revision:
https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm

---

The 2006's version of the C# standard correspond to the .NET framework v.2.0.
The currently revised version correspond to the .NET framework v.5.0.

Microsoft's ".net standard" version 1.0 correspond to the .NET framework v.4.5, and the .net standard version 2.0 correspond to the .NET framework v.4.6.2
The .net standard's GitHub repository can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/standard

Answer (score 0):

ISO/IEC 23270:2006 is, indeed, the correct and latest rev. I'm guessing there will be another shortly when .NET 4.0 rolls out.

A quick [search](http://www.iso.org/iso/search.htm?qt=ISO%2FIEC+23270&sort=rel&type=simple&published=on) of the ISO site confirms it.